# Click/Submit button on another page - Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, get

I am trying to update user preferences from my homepage. (simply done by making a selection and saving on that page)

Can I click/submit this request client side on another page using ajax?

This script doesn't error out... but doesn't seem to 'save' anything...

```
$.ajax({
url: "/mydomain/preferences",
type: "GET",
success:function(data){
  $('#myCheckbox').click();
  $('#mySaveButton').submit();
 }
 });
```

Comment: I don't quite understand... the `#myCheckbox` element, is that on the page that `/mydomain/preferences` delivers? Why not just send to a server-side page, save the information to a database, reply to the client that it was saved, then use client-side JS to forward the user along?

Comment: It's not clear what your intention is. But it reads like you think you could trigger a click/submit on ANOTHER users page from YOUR page using an ajax request on your page. Don't you think this would be a dramatic security breach.

Comment: No.  They are both my pages.